# How to handle events clicks of different views within a row of a ExpandableListView child

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I know how to handle the events by subscribing (setOnClickChildListener) of the ExpandableListView (or overriding the ExpandableListActivity callback method: onChildClick). The two let me know the details groupPosition, childPosition and the view of the row layout (my custom layout for the childs).
But I want to know what particular view has been clicked (for example which textview of my custom row).

I tried it overriding the getView method of the mSimpleCursorTreeAdapter and subscribing my textviews to the onClick listener. But in this way I can't know the groupPosition and the childPosition of the child row clicked. If I handle the onClick of the views in this way, the event is consumed and OnClickChildListener and the callback method onChildClick never will be dispatched.

I guess I am saying something wrong. I hope someone tells me a way to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_child,
                    parent, false);
        }

        TextView textOne = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.text_row_child1);
        TextView textTwo = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.text_row_child2);

        HandleOnClick handleOnClick = new HandleOnClick (
                groupPosition, childPosition, getChildId(groupPosition,
                        childPosition));
        textOne.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick);
        textTwo.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick);

        return super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition,
                isLastChild, row, parent);
    }

    private class HandleOnClick implements OnClickListener {
        private int groupPosition;
        private int childPosition;
        private Long id;

        public HandleOnClick (int groupPostion, int childPosition,
                Long id) {
            this.groupPosition = groupPostion;
            this.childPosition = childPosition;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {

            idChild = id; 
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.text_row_child1:


                break;


            case R.id.text_row_child2:

                //........
```

Thanks

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for a while. I like your approach and I'll probably use it, although defining the click listeners in the adapter feels a bit weird. It would be nicer to define the adapters from the activity itself (maybe on the event of a group being expanded). Thanks for the solution.